# Posting HTML through $_POST in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

This is my form.

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/post_large'); ?>

<textarea name="large"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Post!" />

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

And this is my controller/Method

```
public function post_large()
{
    echo $this->input->post('large');
}
```

When i post plain text.It works fine. but when i post html data like `<a href="#">link</a>`.It post only `<`.How do i post html through my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
public function post_large()
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('large'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. With PHP, the only way to really create an HTML snippet or process it is if you put your HTML code in an echo '', but since a user inputs the data. I recommend creating an HTML form that accepts HTML input, which you can restrict in PHP or Javascript.